# What does Command+s do in MacVim?

Tags: macvim, save

Is a <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> shortcut on a MacVim equivalent to `wa` ? I know that a `wa` will save all the data being displayed in all the viewport. Will the <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> shortcut do the same ?

Comment: Why not just try it and see?

Comment: I tried and it seems like it saves it as wa. However i just wanted to be sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> and it saves only the current file.

It is basically a simple save like <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> or <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> in most GUI programs.

[image]